# Passing wrong type data to component's attributes in React?

Tags: reactjs, type-alias

I'm using type alias with ReactJS and creating a component declared bellow

```js
type PropsType = {
  viewModel: CalendarViewModel,
  onPressDate: void,
  text: string
};
class Calendar extends React.Component<PropsType> { }
```

The problem occurred when i started passing data to render this component. It still renders well when the "text" attribute receives both String and Number data type, but it's just declared to accept only string datatype. So what can i do to fix this?

Comment: What is the type system, typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass either `string` *or* `number`

```
type PropsType = {
  text: string | number,
};
```

Comment: But i only want it to accept string datatype . Moreover,  I actually found that this was a javascript advantage / disadvantage between number and string. Thus i guess there wont be any official ways to solve this